# Is there a way to run workflow when PR review is requested from a specific user

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, pull-request

Well i think the title itself is pretty self explanatory. Right now i can see this in github docs.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [review_requested]
jobs:
  specific_review_requested:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event.requested_team.name == 'octo-team'}}
    steps:
      - run: echo 'A review from octo-team was requested'
```

But i want my workflow to kick off when i request review from a specific user and not a team as suggested by github docs.

Comment: You can run `echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}' >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` and explore the `event` context if it contains some user-related information when a PR review is requested. Apparently, the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) only mentions what you already have included in the question i.e. `github.event.requested_team.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 workflows. From the first one check if your PR request is from specific user, if so - trigger another one in which do whatever you want )